# How can I send input events like taps or swipe to Android with Python if ADB doesn't work?

Tags: android, python-3.x, adb, simulation, androidviewclient

I'm making a script in Python that simulates taps in my device's screen, I use ADB usually but with a game (Clash of Clans), ADB commands doesn't work, I assume that has some anticheat, with screen mirroing using [Scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) mouse inputs works fine, this is how inputs works in [Scrcpy_inputs_events.h](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/app/src/input_events.h)

In practice, there are 3 levels of input events:

- 1. SDL input events (as received from SDL)
- 2. scrcpy input events (this API)
- 3. the key/mouse processors input events (Android API or HID events)

I want to know is there is a way to do the same with Python, cause I've tried some things but all of thems seems to use ADB. My device is rooted if its helps.

I used adb throught cmd ("adb shell input tap x y"), I've also tried using "swipe" instead of "tap".
I'm currently using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to make screenshots, so tried with touch function of it, but didn't work or maybe I'm not using it corretly :

```
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

device.touch(137, 1000)
```

That doesn't raise error, but when I try:

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from culebratester_client.models import Point      # I know this is not used on the script

helper = ViewClient(
    *ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True
).uiAutomatorHelper
helper.ui_device.touch(137, 1000)
```

It raises this:

> CulebraTester2 server should have been started and localport 9987 redirected to remote port 9987.
> 2023-06-29 14:00:22,648 WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000024F75A0E1D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] A connection cannot be established since the destination computer expressly denied the connection')': /v2/uiDevice/dumpWindowHierarchy?format=JSON

I can't use JPython because my code is python3 not python2.

Comment: The error you showed indicates you don't have https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public running and listening on port 9987. You can follow the instructions on that page or add another question here.

Comment: And yes, https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public would be another way of sending event without using `adb`.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thanks for your answer and for developing CulebraTester, I'm not used to sockets or networks in general so I'm so lost, If you could give some indications, I don't understand https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public#how-to-run-culebratester2- , I downloaded "app" and "instrumenation" but don't know how to use that. Can't run https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public#how-to-run-culebratester2- because "configuration" is not defined

Comment: NP, once you downloaded app and instrumentation, install them on your device, and start the server `bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/JT5nc) start-server`. Once the server is running, your AndroidViewClient commands will use it as in the previous example (the one using `helper`).

Comment: I'm working in Windows, as far as I'm concerned "bash" is used in Linux, idk how to do same on Windows.

Comment: Use `git-bash`: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Alternative if you checked out the source you can run `./culebratester2 start-server` instead which will required git-bash on windows as well, but not curl.

Comment: Thanks for your help and knowledge. I've finally done it. :)

Comment: .............